# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method JDocumentError::close()

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I've searched for a solution everywhere but I couldn't find an answer. Some days I got this error without change or do anything:

And I can't access my website in the entire day but suddenly starts working again without any change, and some days later the same problem. What can I do?

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@magic.kiwitextil.com to inform them of the time this error
>   occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My site is: www.magic.cr

I can access to the backend always! (magic.cr/administrator)

I've checked my server logs and I got this lines repeating constantly:

> [23-Aug-2016 16:44:53 UTC] PHP Deprecated: Non-static method
>   JApplication::redirect() should not be called statically, assuming
>   $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/templates/braink/error.php on line
>   9
>
> [23-Aug-2016 16:44:53 UTC] PHP Notice: Undefined property:
>   JDocumentError::$_messageQueue in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   on line 376
>
> [23-Aug-2016 16:44:53 UTC] PHP Notice: Undefined property:
>   JDocumentError::$client in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   on line 394
>
> [23-Aug-2016 16:44:53 UTC] PHP Notice: Trying to get
>   property of non-object in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   on line 394
>
> [23-Aug-2016 16:44:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to
>   undefined method JDocumentError::close() in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   on line 409
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   Lines 376 to 409

```
    if (count($this->_messageQueue))
    {
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('application.queue', $this->_messageQueue);
    }

    // If the headers have been sent, then we cannot send an additional location header
    // so we will output a javascript redirect statement.
    if (headers_sent())
    {
        echo "<script>document.location.href='" . str_replace("'", "&apos;", $url) . "';</script>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();

        jimport('phputf8.utils.ascii');

        if (($this->client->engine == JApplicationWebClient::TRIDENT) && !utf8_is_ascii($url))
        {
            // MSIE type browser and/or server cause issues when url contains utf8 character,so use a javascript redirect method
            echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=' . $document->getCharset() . '" />'
                . '<script>document.location.href=\'' . str_replace("'", "&apos;", $url) . '\';</script></head></html>';
        }
        else
        {
            // All other browsers, use the more efficient HTTP header method
            header($moved ? 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' : 'HTTP/1.1 303 See other');
            header('Location: ' . $url);
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $document->getCharset());
        }
    }

    $this->close();
```

/home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/templates/braink/error.php
Lines 8 to 10
        case "404":
            JApplication::redirect("index.php/404-error"); // replace the redirect URL with your own
            break;

Please help I cannot access my site in the last 36 hours!!!

Comment: Just a guess but have you or your hosting company updated you PHP version recently

Comment: Wondering why this question is tagged `.htaccess`? PHP will generate a 500 error if a "PHP Fatal error" occurs and there is no output (eg. errors not displayed and logged only), which looks like it might be the case here.

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly: I did not I'm not sure about my hosting company (GoDaddy) but they can't offer me a solution beacuse they say "administrator site works so the server works".

Comment: the problem is in your template + what version of joomla 3.x are you using and what php version is running on the server ?

Comment: Hi @moped I'm running Joomla 3.6.2, and PHP Version 5.6.23

Comment: you should start with `braink/error.php on line 9` as I believe this leads to the error

Comment: also, this may be helpful: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16032/how-to-redirect-user-with-system-message-in-joomla-3/16041

Comment: Thanks @moped you are very helpful but I'm an amateur on PHP and this kind of things, can you help me a little more with what I have to do, please? I read the other post but I do not understand how to fix it with my actual skills -.-

Comment: Try to replace `JApplication::redirect("index.php/404-error");` with `$app = JFactory::getApplication(); $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php/404-error'));`

Comment: @moped
Done! but it's not working.
Can you email me to mauricio@magic.cr to talk easier and if I have to pay something I wlll but I need to fix it as soon as possible.